# Using postsharp how to customize OnEntry logging text?

Tags: c#, postsharp

How to customize postsharp logging text inside onEntry method in c#. Look at the screenshot, here first line is mehod_abc starting. In next line I can see the total execution time. I want to eliminate the line 'starting..'. How can I customize this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently (in version 6.8) PostSharp Logging doesn't support this level of customization. As an alternative you can use a custom profiling aspect to measure and log the execution time of methods.

You can start with our sample and modify it for your requirements: https://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.Profiling/